# Need your help to troubleshoot an Aerospike restore issue

Tags: aerospike

I am new to Aerospike and need your help to troubleshoot a restore issue. I have Aerospike running on my mac and it seem to work all fine except that it do not allow me to restore from .asb file. I took backup from an aerospike instance running on an Ubuntu machine using asbackup utility. But when I try to restore the .asb file using asrestore command on my mac instance, it throws following exception:

> asrestore -d ~ 
>   restoring: host 127.0.0.1 port 3000 bin_list (null) from directory /home/vagrant  
>   2015-08-25 15:13:43 INFO Add node BB9A9EAAB270008 127.0.0.1:3000  
>   Aug 25 2015 15:13:43 GMT: starting restore: filename: /home/vagrant/BB9A3F5AA1ED512_00000.asb FILE 0x7f63680008c0  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   put failed in restore: unusual error 20 trying again  
>   restore: too many consecutive put failure  
>   Aug 25 2015 15:13:44 GMT: expired 0 : skipped 0 : attempted 0 : [updated 0 not-updated (existed 0 gen-old 0)]

I tried using -t option to restrict the thread count, but no respite.

Has any one faced a similar issue?

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 20 indicates a bad namespace parameter. Check your server errorlog for more details. Seems like the namespace that is there in the backup file is not defined in the configuration of the cluster where you are trying to load using asrestore.

Two options

1. Create a namespace with the same namespace name as in the backup file
2. Write a script to change the namespace name in the backup files to the intended name which is valid in the cluster where you are trying to load.

The backup file format is documented at http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/backup/file_format.html

Comment: thank you Sunil. I was under the impression that namespace will get created automatically through the restore process.